# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported element: rss

Tags: java, rss, ninjaframework

I am trying to 'GET' a rss feed.

```
 public RssFeed(String url) {
    _url = url;
    String res = this.api.get(url);
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(res.getBytes());

    try {
        bis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(bis);
    try {
        Object xml = decoder.readObject();
        _response = xml.toString();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        decoder.close();
    }
}
```

When I check what's inside of 'res'. It appears to get this entire XML.
But then, I am trying to decode it and I get:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported element: rss`

Can someone help me with that? I am new to Java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XMLDecoder` is meant to be used on elements created by `XMLEncoder`. Since you're scraping this XML from the web, the elements in this XML may not be valid according to these classes. Use a more generic XML parser, such as `DocumentBuilder::parse()` to handle this.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

try {
    builder.parse(url);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```