# XMLDecoder >> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported element

Tags: java, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization, illegalargumentexception

Got this error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported element: net

from this example xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <net>
       <node label="A">
        ...
       </node>
       <node label="B">
        ...
       </node>
       <node label="C">
        ...
       </node>
    </net>
```

with these java code lines

```
    ...
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("example.xml");
    XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(file);
    Object decodedResistors = (Object) decoder.readObject();
    file.close();
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `java.beans.XMLDecoder` for deserialisation custom `XML` payloads. It was not designed for that. Read article [Long Term Persistence of JavaBeans Components: XML Schema](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/persistence3-139471.html). It contains some example `XML` payloads which can be deserialised back by `XMLDecoder`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<java version="1.4.0" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
    <void id="myController" property="owner"/>
    <object class="javax.swing.JButton">
        <void method="addActionListener">
            <object class="java.beans.EventHandler" method="create">
                <class>java.awt.event.ActionListener</class>
                <object idref="myController"/>
                <string>doIt</string>
            </object>
        </void>
    </object>
</java>
```

If you need to deserialise custom `XML` use `JAXB` or `Jackson XML`. You need to create a `POJO` model with `JAXB` annotations:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "net")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Net {

    @XmlElement(name = "node")
    private List<Node> nodes;

    // getters, setters, toString
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Node {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String label;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Example usage:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class JaxbApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File xmlFile = new File("./resource/test.xml").getAbsoluteFile();

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Net.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Object net = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
        System.out.println(net);
    }
}
```

prints:

```
Net{nodes=[Node{label='A'}, Node{label='B'}, Node{label='C'}]}
```

See also:

- [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported element: rss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48711270/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-unsupported-element-rss)

Comment: I got now an exception in "JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Net.class);" 

 Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]

I have created the class "net"

Comment: @B0r1, probably you need to add some dependencies: [Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.AnnotationReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557308/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-xml-bind-v2-model-annotatio)